# Prove that $A$ is dense in $M \Longleftrightarrow U \cap A \neq \emptyset$ for every nonempty open set $U$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

According to my book, a set $A$ is said to be dense in metric space $M$ if $\bar{A} = M$. I know I need to prove two implications here. I have no clue as for how to do this.

Comment: Hint: Use the set $M\setminus\overline{A}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is dense and $U$ is a non-empty open set, then take $x\in U$. Then $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and then, since $\overline A=M$ and $x\in M$, $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$.

Now, suppose that $A$ is such that $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$ for every non-empty open set $U$. Let $x\in M$ and let $N$ be a neighborhood of $x$. Let $U$ be an open subset of $M$ such that $x\in U$ and $U\subset N$. Then $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$, and this imples that $N\cap A\neq\emptyset$. Since this occurs for each neghborhood of $x$, $x\in\overline A$. Therefore, $\overline A=M$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also prove $\neg p\iff\neg q$ instead of $p\iff q$.

---

If $A$ is not dense in $M$ then $U:=M-\overline{A}$ is not empty.

Also it is open, and this with $U\cap A=\varnothing$.

Converse:

If  $U$ is an open set with $U\cap A=\varnothing$ then $A\subseteq U^{\complement}$ where $U^{\complement}$ is closed.

So $\overline{A}\subseteq U^{\complement}$ and if $U$ is not empty then consequently $\overline{A}\neq M$.

Comment: In the converse part, if $U$ is not empty and $U\cap A =\emptyset$, then $U\subset (M\setminus\overline{A})$, hence this set is not empty.

Comment: @Gribouillis Yes, but why do you mention that? If $U$ is not empty then every subset of its complement is not $M$, so $\overline{A}\neq M$, i.e. $A$ is not dense.

Comment: Well, I felt it was a little more direct than what you wrote, but I may be wrong. Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

$\Rightarrow$). Suppose $\overline{A}=M$. Prove by contradiction. Let $U$ be an non empty open set in $M$ such that $U\bigcap A=\emptyset$. Then there exists an open ball $B(x,r)\subset M$ such that $B(x,r)\bigcap A=\emptyset$ which contradicts with $\overline{A}=M$.

$\Leftarrow$). Suppose for every non empty open set $U$ we have $U\bigcap A\neq\emptyset$. For any $x\in M$ and given any $\varepsilon>0$, then the open ball $B(x,\varepsilon)\bigcap A\neq \emptyset$. By taking $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ and taking $n\rightarrow\infty$, we obtain that $x\in\overline{A}$.